# How to insert a non sequential Id from a table in an insert into clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to insert an ID of table 1 in table2. The problem is the fact that the sequential rows in table 1 do not have a sequential Id. (someone have erased some rows, hence no sequential Ids for the sequential rows)

Doing a `select * from table 1` results in:

Table 1

```
Id    Value1
------------
2       X
4       Y
10      Z
12      XYZ
14      ZD
121     XD
122     ZS
------------
```

The desired result of table 2 is:

```
   Id    Value1   Value2      Date
    -----------------------------------
    1       67       2       2018-05-15
    2       67       4       2018-05-15
    3       67      10       2018-05-15
    4       67      12       2018-05-15
    5       67      14       2018-05-15
    6       67      121      2018-05-15
    7       67      122      2018-05-15
    ------------------------------------
```

The code to insert values in table 2. I only need table 1 to copy the right Id.

```
declare @value int
set @value=(select count(*) from table1) 
while @value>0

            begin
                insert into (table2)
                values ('67',@HOW_TO_RETRIEVE THE CORRECT ID from TABLE 1?,getdate())
                set @value=@value-1

            end
```

of course with @value it will not work, I have tried to use the select clause inside values but to no avail. Thanks.

Comment: Simply create identity column in table 2, it will insert rows in sequential numbers

Answer (score 2):

You do NOT want to use a loop for this type of thing. You can use a select statement in your insert quite easily. Something like this work for you. This is assuming that Id in table2 is an identity. If not we can leverage ROW_NUMBER() to generate sequential values.

```
insert table2
(
    Value1
    , Value2
    , [Date]
)
select '67'
    , Id
    , getdate()
from Table1
```

Answer (score 2):

like this?

```
alter table2 add id bigint identity(1,1)
;
insert table2 (Value1, Value2, Date)
select '67', ID ,getdate()
from TABLE1
;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into table2 (value1, value2, [Date])
select 67, Id, getdate() from table1;
```